# getting java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException over hibernate orm

Tags: spring

I have HibernateInterceptor for a method which takes the hibernate ORM as argument

I am getting java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException when the method is invoked. The cause is shown as

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: $Proxy25.saveData(com.test.orm.Employee$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$bcc67d7, java.util.HashMap)

The saveData(com.test.orm.Employee, java.util.HashMap) is my method.

Following is my aspect code for interceptor

```
 @Around(“@target (com.test.HibernateInterceptorRequired)”)
    public Object interceptCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory(joinPoint.getTarget());
    proxyFactory.addAdvice(hibernateInterceptor);

    Class [] classArray = new Class[joinPoint.getArgs().length];
    for (int i = 0; i < classArray.length; i++)
    classArray[i] = joinPoint.getArgs()[i].getClass();

    return
    proxyFactory
    .getProxy()
    .getClass()
    .getDeclaredMethod(joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), classArray)
    .invoke(proxyFactory.getProxy(), joinPoint.getArgs());
    }
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is here:

```
classArray[i] = joinPoint.getArgs()[i].getClass();
```

You use classes of the actual parameters to build a method signature to look for, therefore you end up with signature such as `$Proxy25.saveData(com.test.orm.Employee$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$bcc67d7, java.util.HashMap)` that doesn't match the real signature.

Perhaps you need to do something with `ProceedingJoinPoint.getSignature()` instead, something like this:

```
Method m = ((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod();
return m.invoke(proxyFactory.getProxy(), joinPoint.getArgs());
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

I even tried like 
if(classArray[i].toString().contains("com.test.orm.Employee")){
          classArray[i] = Employee.class;
}

but it still throws error as 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: $Proxy25.saveData(com.test.orm.Employee, java.util.HashMap)

i missed an thing in my previous post my actually saveData method is like
saveData(Employee employee, Map<String,Long> addressMap) this method is under an interface

Comment: @user513494: If you still get `$Proxy25.saveData(com.test.orm.Employee, java.util.HashMap)`, perhaps you need a `Map` as a second argument?

Comment: Yes i have to send the map as argument, Do you think that it will create problem

Comment: @user513494: `getDeclaredMethod()` performs a lookup by method name and signature. Signature of your method is, as you say, `saveData(Employee, Map)`. If `getDeclaredMethod()` can't find a method with signature `saveData(Employee,HashMap)`, it means thay you supplied `getDeclaredMethod()` with a wrong signature.

Comment: Thanks for your comments i did not get exception now. But i am getting lazing initialize exception under saveData method when accessing a field in employee ORM .